# Build failed unknown property 'packagingOptions'

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-studio-3.2

After Android Studio upgrade to 3.2 version I can't make the build.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   Could not get unknown property 'packagingOptions' for task ':app:packageRelease' of type
>     com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
//important apply fabric pluging AFTER dexguard
apply plugin: 'dexguard'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.appersiano.app”
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 27
        versionName "1.1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // For room database schema
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
        sourceSets {
            androidTest.assets.srcDirs +=
                    files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
        }
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
        }
        release {
            keyAlias ‘*’
            keyPassword ‘*’
            storeFile file('keystore.jks')
            storePassword ‘*’

        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            multiDexEnabled true
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_debug",
            ]
        }

        demo {
            applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
            initWith debug
        }
        release {
            debuggable true
            multiDexEnabled false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')
            proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
            ]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //region Testing

    //region Firebase
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'

    //endregion
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.10.0'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v13'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    android {
        testOptions {
            unitTests {
                includeAndroidResources = true
            }
        }
    }

    //endregion

    //region SupportLibraries
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

    //endregion

    //region thirdPartyLibraries
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.12'
    implementation 'com.github.mancj:SlideUp-Android:2.2.8'
    implementation 'com.auth0.android:jwtdecode:1.1.1'

    //RxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.12'

    // Secure shared preferences
    implementation 'com.scottyab:secure-preferences-lib:0.1.4'

    // Runtime permissions
    implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.5@aar'

    //endregion

    //region networking
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    //endregion

    //region googleServices
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev190-1.23.0'

    //endregion

    //region facebookAuthentication
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0'
    implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.27.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
    }

    //if you do not have fb you need this dependcy
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    //endregion

    //Custom views library
    implementation project(path: ':customlayouts')

    //region dataPersistence
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.1'
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    // Room testing library
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1"
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1'

    //kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation project(path: ':heartbeatview-library')
    implementation project(path: ':whatsqrcode')
    implementation project(path: ':blemanager')

    // Library for parcelable
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.11'
    kapt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.11'

    // Library for dates
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.0'

    // Memory leaks library
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.1'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.6.1'

    dependencies {
        def paging_version = "1.0.0"

        implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:$paging_version"

        // alternatively - without Android dependencies for testing
        testImplementation "android.arch.paging:common:$paging_version"

        // optional - RxJava support
        implementation "android.arch.paging:rxjava2:1.0.1"
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1'

    // Braintree
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.4.0'

    // Google cloud messaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
}
```

How to solve it?

Comment: post full code please

Comment: It's really strange, cause you have no packagingOptions specified in your build.gradle. Have you tried clean build or "Invalidate and restart" for android studio?

Comment: yes, problem persist :(

Answer (score 2):

If you are still having this issue. You should try updating Dexguard to the latest version.

Comment: yes, update dexguard is the unique way to solve this types of problem

Comment: @appersiano was an update of the Dexguard library a fix for you? If so might I inquire from what version and to what version.

Comment: Yes, I simply used the latest available!

Comment: Just did the same and this problem is not an issue anymore.